# Launch application on non-jailbroken iOS device from command line on macintosh

Tags: ios, usb, device, launch

For testing perspective, I have to run test on clean application. For this, I have a requirement to uninstall/ install and then launch app on non-jailbroken device remotely, over the usb. I can do uninstall/install. 
Can anybody explain me to use some command line tool to launch app on device. I need command line, i need to fire this command from other project.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Fruitstrap is not launching app on device. My app is already installed on device. Now one of the test case requires relaunch of application. That i need to automate. Any help !!

Comment: I am looking for info urgently. Any help is appreciated !!!!